# ¿Cómo subir un proyecto de laravel 5.2 a un subdominio de hosting compartido sin SSH?

Tags: laravel

**Hola, por favor necesito saber cómo subir un proyecto de laravel 5.2 a un subdominio en un hosting compartido**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caso de Uso 1

En el primer caso de uso, el más común; imaginemos que necesito subir mi proyecto a la raíz de mi sitio web es decir en “www.example.com” y sabemos que este directorio raíz en la mayoría de los casos es una carpeta llamada public_html.

Ahora lo que debemos hacer a continuación es copiar todos los archivos dentro de la carpeta public de lo que acabamos de subir y colocarlos dentro public_html. De esta manera el index.php que estará allí sera el de nuestra aplicación en laravel.

Subir Proyecto de Laravel a Servidor Compartido

Con esto, todo el contenido que estaba dentro de proyecto_compartido/public ahora esta dentro de nuestro directorio public_html.

Lo siguiente que debemos hacer es editar el archivo index.php en el cual ahora debemos apuntar a una nueva rutas de los require. En este archivo debes buscar en las siguientes lineas (por ahora linea 22 y linea 36)

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

Y debes cambiarlas apuntando a donde se encuentran actualmente, para este ejemplo (Cabe destacar que puedes ubicar tus archivos donde mas te sea cómodo).

```
require __DIR__.'../proyecto_compartido/bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'../proyecto_compartido/bootstrap/app.php';
```

De esta manera al ingresar a nuestro dominio www.example.com por lo menos ya debería arrojarnos un error de Laravel. Aunque con hacer esto ya te debería funcionar.

---

> Caso de Uso 2:

En el caso de que necesites subir tu proyecto no en la raíz de tu dominio, sino dentro de una carpeta, ya sea porque tengas instalado WordPress u otra cosa. En vez de copiar los archivos de public dentro de public_html, debes hacerlo en una carpeta aparte.

Por ejemplo si quieres que este dentro de www.example.com/laraveles debes cortar tu carpeta public de tu proyecto y pegarla dentro de tu directorio public_html, para luego renombrarla como quieras, si la renombras laraveles podrás acceder a /laraveles.

El resto de los pasos es el mismo para todos, solo que tienes que revisar bien el tema de las rutas dentro del index.php

Como organices tus carpetas es tu decisión, y depende de como lo sientas mas ordenado. Solo debes cuidar que todo este bien declarado para que ninguna ruta falle.

**Editar Service Provider**

Si por casualidad tus archivos JS y CSS no cargan, esto es porque hemos movido la ubicación de la carpeta public, esto se puede solucionar indicándole a Laravel una nueva ruta publica.

Esto se dentro de un ServiceProvider, para el ejemplo hemos utilizado AppServiceProvider, dentro del método register debes colocar tu nueva ruta.

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path('public_html');
});
```

Con esto ya debería quedar solucionado, si no es así es que has cometido el grave error de usar rutas relativas para cargar tus recursos en vez de usar los helper de Laravel como es el caso de asset().

**Subir Base de Datos**

Ya que no podemos ejecutar las migraciones, desgraciadamente tendremos que subir nuestra base de datos tal cual lo hacíamos en los años 90. Es decir  haciendo un dump de tu Base de Datos en Local, iniciar sesión en tu phpMyAdmin e importar el dump en la misma. Creo que esto no tiene mayor complicación por lo que creo que no es necesario detallar este punto, más si te queda alguna duda dejalo en los comentarios.

**Configuración de Variables de Entorno**

Recordemos que en nuestro archivo .env se encuentra parte de la configuración importante para que nuestra aplicación funcione, en este debes colocar la configuración de tu aplicación, tus datos de acceso a la Base de Datos, y si vas a utilizar el servicio de correo colocar los datos.

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:vmtSju7wP3qbPMMK1PkEtHuamgJCM5RGoLcSwrreZLA=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://example.com

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=proyecto_compartido
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=deprecado
```

Comment: Bien por responderte, es una pregunta oportuna. Estoy en el supuesto 1 y había entendido en otro post por ahí que no tenía que subir el .env, pero entonces ¿cómo decirle a Laravel donde está la BD, correo, etc.? Si subo solo la carpeta public, ¿tampoco hay ficheros del config? Saludos